# How to reference a cell as the file or folder id for DriveApp?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an app script function that includes IDs for both a doc file tmplate and a Google Drive folder location. I want the ID to be dynamic based on a users input via a cell reference in a Google Sheet.

Is it possible to call this value using a cell reference?

Example: Settings!B9 = Google Doc Template ID

```js
//This value should be the id of your document template that we created in the last step
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('INSERT CELL REFERENCE');
  
  //This value should be the id of the folder where you want your completed documents stored
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('INSERT CELL REFERENCE')
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you would like to pull the id of a drive file/folder from a cell in a given Google sheet?

Comment: Yes, The user would have input the ID in the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to use the [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String)) function and pass `Settings!B9` directly as a cell reference:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const file_id = ss.getRange("Settings!B9").getValue(); // get value in "Settings!B9"
  const folder_id = ss.getRange("Settings!C9").getValue(); // get value in "Settings!C9"
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById(file_id);
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**This can be easily achieved by making use of the `getValue` method.**

Therefore, you will have to add the following lines to your code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SS_ID);
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
var fileId = sheet.getRange(ROW,COL).getValue();
var folderId = sheet.getRange(ROW,COL).getValue();
```

The `getRange` method is used to get the range where these values are and in order to retrieve the actual value, the `getValue` method is used.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Sheet Class - getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column);
- [Apps Script Range Class - getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue).