# Saving slides pdf into a folder defined by a google sheets cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-slides

Overall goal:
Save my pdf in a folder which I define in a google sheets cell

I found this script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819079/save-google-slide-as-pdf-using-google-apps-script#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=How%20about%20this%20sample%20script,file%20format%20automatically%20becomes%20PDF.) where I can save my google slides deck into a pdf which works great.

```
function pdf(){
var blob = DriveApp.getFileById("### Slide file ID ###").getBlob();
DriveApp.createFile(blob);
}
```

I would like to define the destination folder ID with referencing a cell in a spreadsheet. I imagine it would be a variation of the code below I found here [How to reference a cell as the file or folder id for DriveApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65930883/how-to-reference-a-cell-as-the-file-or-folder-id-for-driveapp)? but I am just really lost now.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const file_id = ss.getRange("Settings!B9").getValue(); // get value in "Settings!B9"
  const folder_id = ss.getRange("Settings!C9").getValue(); // get value in "Settings!C9"
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById(file_id);
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id)
}
```

I would have imagined it being something like this but it still saves the pdf into the root folder of my drive

```
function pdf() {
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1j_Ltyx9e8Kb-ywLnJDLl5fzoWpfk3elD9xGvZX665DE");
  const folder_id = ss.getRange("Sheet1!C9").getValue(); // get value in "Sheet1!C9"
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id)
  
  var blob = DriveApp.getFileById("1Jac6DZweMjiikCF5qvyZc367PRyn1RoUSs6Osy_F4n0").getBlob();
  DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFile(BlobSource)) the file inside the folder directly:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const file_id = ss.getRange("Settings!B9").getValue(); // get slides id
  const folder_id = ss.getRange("Settings!C9").getValue(); // get folder id
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id)
  const blob = DriveApp.getFileById(file_id).getBlob();
  folder.createFile(blob); // create pdf file of the slide
}
```

Make sure file id of the slides is located in `Settings!B9` and folder id in `Settings!C9`.

Comment: Thank you it works for moving files from to the right folder, is there any way of saving down the pdf to a specified folder in the first instance. I am going to have a lot of files saved down and I would prefer not to save it to the root folder of my drive. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively if I can automatically retrieve the url of the pdf and inject it into the spreadsheet. Thanks!

Comment: @Mee Please check my updated code. I used your first approach and make it create the file to specifc folder. Folder id and slides id are given by cells in the spreadsheet. I hope this is the direction you want to follow.

Comment: You are amazing! It worked just as I wanted it. You saved me several times now, I really really appreciate it!

Comment: @Mee I am glad it was helpful to you :)